# Software for math sketching

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-software

Usually when you're writing in LaTeX you want some pretty illustrations. 
Right now for geometry figures I use GeoGebra, which is easy enough; but  I usually see better figures on other papers.

Plus, it is not all about geometry: I would like to easily make some custom drawing, so the software should allow me to "write" on the screen (a bit like MSPaint does; but paint looks horrible)

For example say I want to create on the pc this image:[image]

How do I do that? (This one has been written down on paper and then scanned)

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: I use the Tikz package for my LaTex drawing

Comment: I use the same. The learning curve is rather severe but it's very powerful.

Comment: Another possibility is to use vector graphic software like InkScape to make high quality scalable images. It works like Photoshop, in that it's got tools and a nice GUI. So if you have any other graphics background, the learning curve for InkScape might be easier than Tikz. I say this as an alternative; I primarily use Tikz.

Comment: Also, I want to add that the Tex stack exchange (run on the same software as this exchange) offers help on Tikz code.

Comment: Here's a good place to start if you want to get an impression of what TikZ can do: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/all/

Comment: @Jeremy Tikz seems very interesting but also quite challenging to master (I mean I don't want to put in all that effort right now)
Anyhow, can you point to a nice tutorial? :-)

Comment: @Ant As BeaumontTaz mentioned, you can browse the [Tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) site (actually the tikz tag is the most popular) or read the [tikz manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf). I did the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tikz is a popular drawing tool for $\LaTeX$. It is fairly dificult to get going, but the [manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) is very valuable, and there is also a [tex SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf). With a lot of valuable information.

What you can do with it is endless, but it will take time. Note that it is also possible to make simple figures/diagrams in programs such as maple, mathematica and the like and export the images to pdf/post script to include into your document. I've done both in the past and it has worked quite well.

Comment: I'll take a look at it then :) thank you very much!